# Can a button on static HTML file fire database queries and fetch the results in real time?

Tags: html, mysql, database, selenium, testng

I have a database (MySQL) having the count of daily run results from an automation suite. The results are inserted into the database when the automation suite run is over (@AfterSuite).

However, I need to find a way to fetch the results for any particular day and display these from today's run file (index.html). This index.html is a static HTML file that shows the daily results- pass, fail, duration etc.

I am not sure if a button on the index.html can fire database queries and get the results for any particular day. The automation framework uses Java with TestNG.

Comment: consider using jquery

Comment: I have created a solution for this with a webpage showing the results and database for storage of the result and java implementation to add result to the database. If you are intrested you can have the implementation?

Answer (score -1):

you cannot do this with static html.
Only way is to do dynamic html.

Comment: Typically you would use a server application to get the results and build the html that displays it. It **is** possible to do this with static HTML e.g. by posting a <form>. DHTML is just js, css and html running in the browser, so it's not on the server and can't talk to the DB, so you would still have to send requests to the server.